# Oracle table partition on non partitioned table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I have a legacy application currently running on Oracle 11g, a table which has 3 million data from the year of 2003 to to 2022 and data continuously growing. This table has 43 columns.
Because of this huge data, entire application is running slow.

The primary key of this table is used in most of the joins. all the columns are storing numbers except the creation date.

I was thinking of partitioning the table by year or every 6 months or every quarter.
As the data is growing everyday, I should be able to create a partition automatically for upcoming years.

which would be the better way to partition this table.?
how do I do partition on existing non partitioned table.?

Kindly provide some examples I can refer.

Looking for best advises.

Comment: Conversion to partitioned table is not available in 11g via `alter table`. You may use [`DBMS_REDEFINITION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042) package to perform a converion in consistent way. For automated allocation of partitions you may use [interval partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#i2146287)

Comment: In general, you'll need to create a new partitioned table, move the data from the existing table to the new table (probably using a direct-path insert with parallel DML), drop the old table, and rename the new table to use the old name

Comment: @astentx: ok, Interval partition works.